# Using multi iterate of ArcMap ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, iteration

I want to use more than 2 iterates.

The data I have is point.gdb, polygon data.
There are about 2000 point.gdb.
There are about 1000 polygon data.

I want to save the points that exist in the polygon area for each polygon.

So I tried like this:

1. In ModelBuilder 1, I select the point data.gdb I have one by one (save as model1)
2. In ModelBuilder 2, iterates-feature selection is used to select polygon data one by one.
3. Using clip's function
   input feature: read 1 (model1)
   clip feature: read 2 times

Each item is set as a parameter

[image]

When I run it, it turns out that it cannot find the recursive function.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the clip tool into model 1. Then the logic should then be on each iteration in the master model (what you are calling model8) a polygon is fed into the sub model (what you are calling mode 1) and that becomes the clipper for many point datasets.

Comment: Thank you.
I tried to proceed according to your opinion. As you say, the storage name did not have a value value. So, value was specified as a parameter and the storage path was specified using %value%. But it failed. As you say, can you get the value of model 8 and specify it as the save file name?